# Bluehost Automatic Sub-domain Creation

Tags: subdomain, automation

I am working on a small project in which people create an account and they are given a sub-domain like username.mydomain.com

However, while this address is shown in the address bar of the browser, the page actually exists at something like mydomain.com/?profile=12345.

This would all be automatic.

Is this possible with a standard Bluehost account running cPanel?

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of their helpdesk articles:

Yes! Bluehost does support the creation of Wildcard DNS/Subdomains. You are welcome to create these from your cPanel -> Domains -> Subdomains section.  https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/527

And for subbdomains:  https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/search?sort=&search=addon&x=0&y=0&search_all=1&search_kb=1&search_video=1&search_started=1

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using Apache URL rewriting (something similar was asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain).

Comment: I don't believe most hosts allow users to set up wildcard subdomains.